If a parent/guardian witnesses a child commit a crime and doesn't report it, can they face legal reprecussions?
Molly the Mother witnesses Darla the Daughter doing a crime. For whatever reason (e.g. not wanting her daughter to have it on her permanent record, believing it was just a mistake), Molly doesn't report the crime.
Later, Darla is taken in for the crime and reveals her mother knew but didn't report it. Can Molly the Mother face legal repercussions?
Examples of crimes Darla could've committed:

Underage drinking or smoking weed
Shoplifting
Assault with a weapon
Manslaughter

The only relevant legal thing I know is that a spouse can't be forced to testify against their partner.
